# Auto generate array from column

Tags: php, arrays, populate

I am making a form that builds itself from a given db and table. However I have come across a snag when it comes to the Insert function. I already made it so that all the fields generate input, textareas what have you on a page with the correct name. Now all I need to do is insert it into the db on post. But I need to recreate the array in format (this,that,this) using implode and I'm not sure how to do this.

```
 $resultInsert = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM " . $table);
$fieldnames=array();

if (mysql_num_rows($resultInsert) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultInsert)) {
            echo $fieldnames[] = $row['Field']; #currently outputting titlebodytextcreated (three fields i have)
        }
      }


// FORMAT: field_name = $_POST[fieldname]

$values = array('title'=>$_POST['title'],'bodytext'=>$_POST['bodytext']); # need this to be autogenerated by the field names

echo "<br>" . sprintf('INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES ("%s")', 'testdb', 
implode(', ', array_map('mysql_escape_string', array_keys($values))), implode('", "',array_map('mysql_escape_string', $values))); 

// add loop for id to be generated in a hidden field, along with all other excluded fields so that the
// update will process correctly in the insert into phase
```

Comment: this is really bothering me haha. im kindof a noobie to php. but i really want to get this code to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work?

```
$values = array_intersect_key( $_POST, array_flip($fieldnames) );
```

or, rather, if you want to ensure that all values in `$fieldnames` have a key in `$values` even when the corresponding key in `$_POST` is empty:

```
$values  = array_flip($fieldnames);  
$values += array_intersect_key( $_POST, $values );
```

Comment: seems to be working! thanks! im going to run some more tests but i think u nailed it

Comment: how would one apply this method to an update field? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277580/dynamic-array-creation-for-update-mysql-php