# Dynamic array creation for mysql update - php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

How would I create an dynamic query like that in insertIntoDb for updateDbRecord? Given that I want to update a specific ID using `update_id=$_GET['id'];` since my ID is stored in my URL i.e. somepage.php?id=12

```
function insertIntoDb($db, $table, $carry, $carryUrl) {
    mysql_select_db($db) or die("Could not select database. " . mysql_error());
    $resultInsert = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM " . $table);
    $fieldnames=array();
      if (mysql_num_rows($resultInsert) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultInsert)) {
            $fieldnames[] = $row['Field'];
            $values = array_intersect_key( $_POST, array_flip($fieldnames) );
        }
      }
      $sql = sprintf('INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES ("%s")', $table, 
      implode(', ', array_map('mysql_escape_string', array_keys($values))), implode('", "',array_map('mysql_escape_string', $values))); 
      mysql_query($sql);
      /* if ($carry == 'yes') {
        redirect($carryUrl.'?id='.$_REQUEST['id']);
      }
      else { echo '<div class="success">Data was entered into the database successfully!<br><a href="view.php?type=recent">View listing?</a></div>'; } */
}

function updateDbRecord($db, $table) {
    mysql_select_db($db) or die("Could not select database. " . mysql_error());
    $resultInsert = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM " . $table . " WHERE Field NOT IN ('id')");
    $fieldnames=array();
      if (mysql_num_rows($resultInsert) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultInsert)) {
            $fieldnames[] = $row['Field'];
            $values = array_intersect_key( $_POST, array_flip($fieldnames) );
        }
      }
      #update syntax
}
```

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 1):

something along [these](http://ideone.com/oK6K5) lines to create the update statement.

```
// todo sanitise with mysql_escape_string()
foreach($arr as $key => $v) {
    $val = is_numeric($v) ? $v : "'" . $v . "'";

    $set .= sprintf("%s=%s%s", $key, $val, ($v == end($arr) ? "" : ", "));
}

$sql = sprintf("UPDATE %s SET %s", $table, $set);
```

Comment: $sql = sprintf("UPDATE %s SET %s WHERE id=".$_GET['id'], $table, $set);    doesnt seem to be working?

Comment: @Alex have you checked the value of `$sql`, is the value of `$_GET['id']` correct? why not do it like `sprintf("UPDATE %s SET %s WHERE id=%s", $table, $set, $_GET['id']);`

Comment: i made a few changes in the form by adding a hidden input field that gets the id as written in the url then posts it to the update sprintf. Working like a charm! thanks tom!

Comment: Tom it seems like there is a problem arising after all UPDATE projects SET project_name='asd', project_bold='sadasd', project_content='', WHERE id='12'  - the last field in the array has a comma which is preventing it from working. is there a way of using implode to fix this?

Comment: @Alex should be fixed, look at [impode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) there is a function to implode associative arrays, [here](http://ideone.com/A5HrG) is an adaption. don't forget to pass `$key` and `$val` to [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) or similar